# MySQL in Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, html, database, wordpress

So, second part.

I now got the data for the mysql database but everytime I include a mysql function in the wordpress HTML editor (with exec-php enabled) the site is empty (except for the standard design and the title of the site in the tab is "Site not found" when before everything worked great.

Any idea? What is WordPress problem?

```
    if(isset ($_POST['name']))
    {
        if($_POST['name'] == "" || $_POST['adresse1'] == "" || $_POST['adresse2'] == "" || $_POST['land'] == "" || $_POST['tel'] == "" || $_POST['email'] == "" || $_POST['interessen'] == "")
        {
            echo "Mindestens eine Angabe fehlt leider.";

echo "<br/><br/><a href=\"javascript:history.back()\">Zurück</a>";
        }
        else
        {
            mysql_connect("xx","xx","xx") or die(mysql_error());
        }
    }
```

This is my code, $_POST works okay and the form is also shown. But when I try to use a mysql_connect it loads no text and don't give an error report too. And the title in the tab bar changes to "Site not found". But with phpmyadmin i can access the database.

Comment: What was the first part? Can you include some sample code? What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: If I just insert this one into the code 
`$db = mysql_connect("localhost","dbxx6728","lusxxx608");`

My site won't load and will just display the title set in WordPress, like it stops the loading action. Trying to have a form that is saved in a MySQL DB, done that thousand times before but WP makes it hard!

Comment: You need to look at the error log file. If you're on Linux, it's probably in /var/log/apache2/error.log

Comment: Can you add your code sample to your question? Also, are you putting that inside a php code block?

Comment: Okay, I added it. I use <?php with exec-php, works good.

Comment: @LiamSchnell Does that mean you have it working?

Comment: No, mysql_connect still doesn't work, just an empty post shows up and I can't find the damn error log on this hoster.

Answer (score 0):

Enable wordpress debug-mode and look at your error-log.
To enable debug-mode, put the following into your wp-config.php:

```
/** Debugging WP */
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('SCRIPT_DEBUG', true);
```

Additionally look at the error-log of your webserver.